# Python OOP and Recursion: when to put "self" and when not to

Tags: python-3.x, oop, recursion, self

In a recursive function in Python OOP, the use of the prefix "self." seems to get a bit murky.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__():
        ...

    def flatten(self, ...):
      nodeQueue = queue.Queue(10)

      ...

      nodeQueue.put(...)
      nodeQueue.get()

      ...

      self.flatten(...)
      ...
```

Q1. If *nodeQueue* is accessed across every layer of the recursion, should it be:
self.*nodeQueue* OR *nodeQueue*

Q2. The parameter of *flatten(...)* denoted by `...`, should that have the "self" prefix as well? Concretely, let one of the parameters be `layerDepth = 0`. And at each recursion call, `layerDepth += 1` happens. So, should it be `self.layerDepth ...` OR `layerDepth ...`

Given my two questions, I hope for an answer that outlines the general rules of the usage of `self.` in the context of recursive function in OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the code of a method:

- a variable name prefixed with `self.` is a member field of the object from which you called the method;
- a variable name not prefixed with `self.` is either a local (temporary) variable of the method, or another variable from a larger scope (*i.e.*, a global variable).

Perhaps this can answer your question:

```py
>>> x = 5
>>> class Myclass:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = 3
...   def printme(self):
...     print(self.x)
...   def printhim(self):
...     print(x)
... 
>>> o = Myclass()
>>> o.printme()
3
>>> o.printhim()
5
>>> class Theotherclass:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.y = 3
...   def printme(self):
...     print(self.y)
...   def printher(self):
...     print(y)
...   def print10(self):
...     y = 10
...     print(y)
... 
>>> o = Theotherclass()
>>> o.printme()
3
>>> o.print10()
10
>>> o.printher()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in printher
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>> y = 8
>>> o.printher()
8
>>> o.print10()
10
>>> o.printher()
8
>>> print(o.y)
3
```

In particular, note how `print10` has no impact on the value of the outside variable `y` nor on `o.y`; and calling `o.y` from the main scope or `self.y` from `o`'s method `printme` refers to the same member field `y` of `o`.